# Carrierwave and Jcrop, delete original after crop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jcrop

I'm having a difficult time getting Carrierwave to delete the original file after the cropped versions are made. I'm making a 600 pixel version of the upload for the user to crop but after the crop I want that version to get deleted since it's never used on the site.

I've tried several solutions found online but they all delete the large version before the crop, not after.

Here is my Carrierwave uploader:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Only allows jpg, jpeg, or png
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  resize_to_limit(600, 600)

  version :profile do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(120, 120)
    def full_filename (for_file = model.file) 
      "profile.png" 
    end
  end

  version :timeline do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(50, 50)
    def full_filename (for_file = model.file) 
      "timeline.png" 
    end
  end

  version :navigation do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(20, 20)
    def full_filename (for_file = model.file) 
      "navigation.png" 
    end
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use an `after_store` callback to remove the original file (using `File.delete`) or you could modify the original so that it's the largest size you need:

```
version :normal do
   process :resize_to_limit => [600,600]
end
```

Comment: after_store does not seem to work in this case because the cropping does not happen at the moment of upload. So the large file gets stored, and then deleted before I can use jCrop to edit it.

Comment: @RichCoy you could move the delete logic to the `after_save` callback of saving the edited image

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Would that go in the uploader or in the controller?

Comment: You can use it in the uploader  as described here - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

For those who will try to solve the issue for the case of adding some revision information to the image name (e.g. cropping), I found a way to do this.

```
# :large is the cropped version
version :small_square, from_version: :large do 
  before :cache, :reset_revision
  after :store, :remove_old_revision

  def full_filename(for_file)
    fname = super(for_file)
    "#{ fname.pathmap('%n') }_#{ model.image_revision }#{ fname.pathmap('%x') }"
  end

  def full_original_filename
    "#{ super.pathmap('%n') }_#{ model.image_revision }#{ super.pathmap('%x') }"
  end

  def remove_old_revision(file = nil)
    File.delete(@old_path) if @old_path && File.exists?(@old_path)
  end

  def reset_revision(file = nil)
    # Otherwise we'll get `cannot update new record` error
    if model.persisted?
      # Creating an instance variable that will be used after storing the cropped version
      @old_path = File.join(Rails.public_path, model.public_send(mounted_as).store_dir, full_original_filename)

      # I use :image_revision column in the DB
      model.update_columns(image_revision: SecureRandom::hex(8))
    else
      model.image_revision = SecureRandom::hex(8)
    end
  end

  process :crop_small_square
end
```

So, it's storing the path of the first version of the cropped version before changing the resulting image name and then deleting the first version.

Took me some time to figure out the way to attach some abracadabra to the end of a definite version of file: it takes the update action, rather than just assigning the attribute. Carrierwave's docs aren't that accurate.